# I need a trigger that when doing insert, update or delete, update a table with the repeated values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a trigger that when doing insert, update or delete, update a table with the repeated values ​​of another table.

Example:
[image: count repeated values of another table]

Comment: Are you sure you need trigger or would [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) be sufficient?

Comment: mysql or sql-server? please always just tag one database system

Comment: In this case I need to be saved to be able to do statistics from that.

Sorry, only mysql

Comment: What problems do you have in writing the triggers (you will need 3)?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a trigger? Unless you have a ridiculously huge amount of data, it would be much easier to just create a view with this summary, instead of having to store repeated data and make sure you keep updating it:

```
CREATE VIEW estadistica
AS
SELECT   id AS letra, COUNT(*) AS estadistica
FROM     tabla1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Because I want to update the table every time someone does an update, insert or delete

Comment: @AlanRodriguez A view will give you exactly that functionality. A view doesn't store any data, just the query, so whenever you query from it, the underlying query is executed, and you'll see an updated result.

Comment: You're right, but in this case I need to be saved to be able to do statistics from that.

Comment: @AlanRodriguez again - why not calculate statistics from the view?